# build commands failed Run custom shell script 'Run Script'

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to build react native code on M1 Mac. I'm using "react-native": "0.72.6".
the same code builds for iOS on another Mac machine but is giving an error on mine

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AD63AA55-46D7-4B7C-B387-CE981D615DA0, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AD63AA55-46D7-4B7C-B387-CE981D615DA0, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Run custom shell script 'Run Script'
    eyJ0eXBlIjp7IndvcmtzcGFjZSI6e319fQ==
(2 failures)
```

as suggested by a comment from Vickey I ran the build in Xcode and here's the error

```
[Warning] You need to configure your node path in the `".xcode.env" file` environment.  You can set it up quickly by running:  `echo export NODE_BINARY=$(command -v node) > .xcode.env`  in the ios folder. This is needed by React Native to work correctly.  We fallback to the DEPRECATED behavior of finding `node`. This will be REMOVED in a future version.  You can read more about this here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#optional-configuring-your-environment
/Users/personal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RenoCustomer-cgqxlbllsloufxgvbxroygfuojbf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAppDelegate.build/Script-46EB2E00043050.sh: line 5: /Users/personal/Documents/reno-customer-app/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/react-native/scripts/codegen/generate-legacy-interop-components.js: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try to run the app from Xcode and see the descriptive reason of build failure, also you can attach the reason here so people can help you.

Comment: I have edited the post to show the error from Xcode

Comment: Do you have `.xcode.env` file in your ios folder?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred after I upgraded React Native to the fabric architecture. The reason is that when Xcode compiles to obtain the node, it searches it from the /usr/local/bin/node path. Even if I use brew h or nvm to install it, it is also in another path, through The method of creating soft links provided by developers on GitHub also failed to solve my problem; I solved this problem by completely uninstalling node and then reinstalling it using the pkg package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).